# Using Google Translate API V2 on Google App Engine project

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-api, google-translate

I'm setting up a Google App Engine project that provides a simple XMPP translation service:
Send a message to the bot using Google Talk, the bot replies with the translated message.

In Eclipse, I added the Google Translate API, however it added the V2 API (`google-api-translate-v2-java.jar`)
Now, there's nowhere I can find any documentation or sample on how to use this [labs](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html) api.

Can anybody provide me with a simple sample on how to translate a message using that API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples are right there on the link you provided: 
http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html#REST

Some other examples here:
http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v1/getting_started.html#hiworld

Java non-official API:
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/

Comment: Thanks, but looking for a Java sample. Feels strange that they provide a `.jar` when you still call the URL manually

Comment: Where did you get that jar? Are you sure that's official Google API? Edited answer.

Comment: Yes, it installed by using the official Google Eclipse plugin. That lightweight jar you provided looks nice aswell. It will be my next option. I'll give myself a 20 minute time limit to find an 'official' solution :-)

Answer (score 2):

The Google Translate API has been deprecated, as of May 26, 2011. It will be shut off completely on Dec 1, 2011

http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [google-translate-api-v2-java](http://code.google.com/p/google-translate-api-v2-java/)